# Do the weights of IPTW have to sum up to the population size?

Tags: logistic, python, causality, propensity-scores, weighted-data

I'm new to Inverse Probability of Treatment Weighting and trying to understand the mechanism. From several practical guides I understood, that the weights should add up to the population size for treated and untreated samples (e.g., [here](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/11-Propensity-Score.html) or [here](https://academic.oup.com/ckj/article/15/1/14/6358134)). Now I have a dataset with unbalanced treatment data and non-normal distributed confounders, which looks something like this:

```
N = 10000
confounder = np.random.pareto(5, N)
treatment = np.random.logistic(0.05,confounder, N)
treatment = np.where(treatment > 0.5, 1,0)
y = 0.5 * treatment + 0.1 * confounder
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'y' : y,
        'treatment' : treatment,
        'confounder' : confounder,
    }
)
```

when I now calculate the propensity scores with logistic regression and weight the samples, they don't sum up to the population size

```
t = df["treatment"]
X = df[["confounder"]]
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    (
        'logistic_classifier',
        LogisticRegression(
            class_weight='balanced',
            C=1,
            max_iter=100,
            warm_start=True,
            random_state=42
        )
    )
])
pipe.fit(X, t)
df['proba'] = pipe.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]

weight_t = 1/df[df["treatment"]==1]["proba"]
weight_nt = 1/(1-df[df["treatment"]==0]["proba"])

print("Original Sample Size", df.shape[0])
print("Treated Population Sample Size", sum(weight_t))
print("Untreated Population Sample Size", sum(weight_nt))

----------

Original Sample Size 10000
Treated Population Sample Size 1999.821396311078
Untreated Population Sample Size 46710878272.35123
```

I have the feeling, that I'm doing something wrong with the calculation of the propensity scores but I don't understand what is wrong. The `class_weight='balanced'` option should correct for the unbalanced treatment variable.

Comment: Where in the CKJ article do you see that the weights should sum to a specific value? And what makes you think you should be correcting for an unbalanced treatment variable?

Comment: 1) fair point. They don't explicitly state it. I just assumed it from the illustration, having read the other article before. 
2) From my understanding  the logistic regression will not properly predict unbalanced classes

Comment: Logistic regression is used without modification for PS weighting. There is no need to balance classes. I am not familiar with any result saying that the weights should sum to the sample size, though that may be the case incidentally in some examples. There is a related phenomenon with stabilized weights described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/476625/116195). It should be noted that the weights are invariant to scaling, so what they sum to doesn't matter when using most modern estimators of the treatment effect after weighting.